# Center two <section> tags next to each other

Tags: html

Hi i am very new at html and css and i have just started to learn. I want to center two  tags next to each other so they are completly in the middle of the page with all the text and content inside it. I have almost got it to work but the section boxes are a bit to te left... I have no idea how to fix it right now so i hope you could help :)

Here are the css:

```
 section{
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 border-style: dotted;
 float: left;
 width: 45%;
 height: auto;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 5px;
}
```

The site then looks like this:
[Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqh4g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modern and easy way of doing this is by using flexbox. You can do this by giving a container-div (or any semantic version of the div - main, article etc.) the following properties:

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

<div id="container">
    <section>Content</section>
    <section>Content</section>
</div>
```

Instead of center you can also use space-between/space-around depending on what you want to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/3qk981mk/1/

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Fun game to learn the flexbox technique:
http://flexboxfroggy.com/

---

If you want to do it the old school way, you would use the following css on the container:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

That would give 0 margin vertically and center the content horizontally.

But go with flexbox, it's cool as heck!

Comment: Cool. Keep in mind some older browsers might not be supported, if that's a requirement. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox